# Catching SoapExceptions from ASP.net Webservices

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, exception

I have a windows forms client that consumes an ASP.net web service.

It's my understanding that when an exception is thrown by the web service it will be converted to a SoapException in the .net client software.

Well, I am catching the SoapException, but when I display the message on the client end in a messagebox, it shows more information than I really want to show.

Here is the webservice code:

```
throw new ApplicationException("Invalid username or password.");
```

Or even:

```
throw new SoapException("Invalid username or password.", SoapException.ServerFaultCode);
```

But on the client end, the SoapException's Message property is this:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Invalid username or password. at Transportation.InsertSignUps(String username, String password, SignUp[] signUps) in c:\Documents and Settings\rdoverby\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\www.gtcc.edu\App_Code\webservices\Transportation.cs:line 50
```

Whereas, all I really want to show is:

```
Invalid username or password.
```

How can I extract ONLY the original exception's message from the SoapException. I have poked around the SoapException object in the VS debugger, but I can't find what I am looking for.

Thanks.

### EDIT

Of course, I don't want to parse that long string.

Comment: I have been struggling with this, creating a simple response class with the error message is the best option.  See this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32058/945875

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screw it. I just returned a string from the service containing any error messages. If the string is null then the service did its job.

Silence is golden.

Answer (score 1):

if the exception is a soapException (se) then you can get to the most important bits by using something like se.Detail.FirstChild.OuterXml which is where the Exception is usually placed or if you want the lot then se.Detail.OuterXml

Answer (score 0):

Tried `Exception.InnerException.Message` ?

Comment: Yes. InnerException is null. There is no way to get to the original exception from client code.

Answer (score 0):

Derive a new exception class from SoapException and set the message property directly.

Comment: I can't do that. It doesn't matter whether I throw an Exception, ApplicationException, SoapException, CustomSoapException, or a YourMomTurnsTricksException. The webservice will send xml <Fault> and the consumer will turn that into a SoapException.

Comment: So then the extra text is added on the client side? Interesting. I guess you could manipulate the serialization of the exception but that sounds hard. Probably just parse the string :p

Answer (score 0):

You need to throw your own exception, custom or whatever, and then when the client throws the soap exception, the Detail property should have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be too disappointed:)

I've did the same with the help of this article: http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3088231.

I've created one custom class for my exceptions, and it even has the real Exception as an InnerException encapsulated in it. (I've added a language-independent ID to every known type of my custom Exceptions, to make it more usable for my clients.)

On the client side, I just get the InnerException, and InnerException.Message is the original text, without any garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't see this before.

I believe the true answer is to configure `<customErrors/>` on the server. I forget which mode you want, but one of the three will limit the amount of detail in the exception that the client receives. It's not what you'd expect, and I didn't believe it myself. Someone posted this answer on another forum and when I tried it, it worked. Nothing I had tried got rid of the detail.

Answer (score 0):

The SoapException's detail property contains the original serialized exception under the SerializedExeption node.

You can try using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter to deserialized the exception using a method similar to one described here:
http://blog.irm.se/blogs/eric/archive/2005/03/06/An-ExceptionHandler-that-extract-the-detail-information-from-the-SoapException.aspx

I was not able to make it work, however, as I ended up getting the "no assembly associated with Xml key" error from the Soap Formatter.

You can drill down the SerializedException node manually as it essentially contains a base-64-encoded SOAP envelope:

```
        string serializedException = exception.Detail.SelectSingleNode("SerializedException").InnerText;
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(serializedException)));
```

The resulting XmlDocument will contain some interesting information, including what appears to be an xml-serialized exception.