# How do you catch a thrown soap exception from a web service?

Tags: c#, soap, service, exception

I throw a few soap exceptions in my web service successfully. I would like to catch the exceptions and access the string and ClientFaultCode that are called with the exception. Here is an example of one of my exceptions in the web service:

```
throw new SoapException("You lose the game.", SoapException.ClientFaultCode);
```

In my client, I try to run the method from the web service that may throw an exception, and I catch it. The problem is that my catch blocks don't do anything. See this example:

```
try
{
     service.StartGame();
}
catch
{
     // missing code goes here
}
```

How can I access the string and ClientFaultCode that are called with the thrown exception?

Comment: I have been struggling with this, creating a simple response class with the error message is the best option.  See this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32058/945875

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Catch the `SoapException` instance. That way you can access its information:

```
try {
     service.StartGame();
} catch (SoapException e)  {
    // The variable 'e' can access the exception's information.
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure Lou won't break his code with this change, he may add an additional block `catch (Exception e)`. sometimes it is possible that the exception is not `SoapException`... e.g.: `OutOfMemoryException`, or connectivity problem, or thread abort, etc.

Comment: This works well. However, I have a question. How can I find out what the string is really called so I can access it? For example: e.GetString() or something. For this particular example, I want to access the string "You lose the game."

Comment: I can call e.Message which returns a very long error message, but I only want the string message.

Comment: Louise, I don't know your situation, but I guess you can create classes inherited from `SoapException` with whatever additional information you need. Then add catch blocks for these classes **before** catching as described here.

Comment: Louise: `e.Message` returns **exactly** the same string as was passed to constructor, I tested. Maybe you used some other exception class, that added extra information to your message?

Comment: Or you handled another exception, which wasn't thrown by you. Such exception may occur at service-side, and it would be **wrapped** to `SoapException` by CLR.

Comment: Also note, that `SoapException.ClientFaultCode` according to MSDN "Specifies a SOAP fault code that represents a client call that is not formatted correctly or does not contain the appropriate information." It it exactly what you wish? Maybe, you should use another code, or another constructor. Just warning.

Answer (score 10):

You may want to catch the specific exceptions.

```
try
{
     service.StartGame();
}
catch(SoapHeaderException)
{
// soap fault in the header e.g. auth failed
}
catch(SoapException x)
{
// general soap fault  and details in x.Message
}
catch(WebException)
{
// e.g. internet is down
}
catch(Exception)
{
// handles everything else
}
```

Comment: this doesn't answer Louise's question

Answer (score 1):

```
catch (SoapException soapEx) 
{
  //Do something with soapEx
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the full SOAP response and get an error message with more detail you can start with this:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
   string inner_message = string.Empty;
   try 
   {
      FaultException faultException = (FaultException)ex;
      MessageFault msgFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();
      XmlElement elm = msgFault.GetDetail<XmlElement>(); 
      inner_message = elm.InnerText;
   }

   string full_message = ex.Message + " " + inner_message;
}
```

Based on the complexity of the XML you can try and get inner tags or info on the way you need. The XmlElement variable will store all the info.